# Hash set implementation using dynamically allocated array of implementation of Linked lists

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, hash, hashset

I am running into trouble with the concept of templates. My linked list class is templated and so is my hash set.

In my private variables for my hash set, I represent the set as such:

```
LinkedList<T>* hashTab;
```

and I get the error

```
expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
**LinkedList<T>*** hashTab;
```

this is how I default construct the hash set

```
hashTab = new LinkedList[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
```

Theses classes are in separate header files in the same folder. What could be the cause of this error??

example:

A.hpp

```
template<typename T>
class A{
    public: 
    A();
};
```

B.hpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

template<typename T>
class B{
    private:
    A<T>* hashTab;
    public: 
    B();
};

template <typename T>
B::B(){
    hashTab = new A[10];
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Your edit [doesn't reproduce any issue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wbt2spoqo8tEeQGl)...

Comment: @AndyG i did that

Comment: @AndyG I deleted the last part thats on my new edit from my old edit on accident

Comment: Please put together a complete example, without breaks in the middle, that reproduces the error.  It doesn't help that we have to put together a jigsaw puzzle.

Comment: The title doesn't really reflect the problem you were having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your template member functions outside of your class, you must provide the template arguments for `B`, and you must always provide them for the member `A<T>*`:

```
template <typename T>
B<T>::B(){
    hashTab = new A<T>[10];
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o8rtQMKVgODsmmF3)